# DateTime picker bug

Tags: jquery, datetime, picker

I'm using jquery datetime picker and when I open the page where those pickers are, then both pickers value is current time (for example: Sat Nov 01 2014 08:27:28 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)). How to set 12:00 by default selected value, not current time?

Thank you guys...

http://jsfiddle.net/4fa5n7wa/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();

    var minStart = new Date();
    minStart.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);

    var minEnd = new Date(minStart);
    minEnd.setDate(minEnd.getDate() + 2);

    $("#start").datetimepicker({
        format: "Y/m/d H:i",
        dayOfWeekStart: "1",
        value: "12:00",
        inline: true,
        lang: "nl",
        onSelectDate: function (ct) {
            var diff = CalcDiff();

            var minDate = new Date(ct);
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 2);

            if (diff > 48)
                var defDate = new Date($("#end").val());

            $("#end").datetimepicker("destroy");
            $("#end").datetimepicker({
                format: "Y/m/d H:i",
                dayOfWeekStart: "1",
                value: "12:00",
                inline: true,
                lang: "nl",
                minDate: minDate,
                defaultDate: defDate || minDate,
                onSelectDate: function (ct) {
                    CalcDiff();
                },
                onSelectTime: function (ct) {
                    CalcDiff();
                }
            }).val(defDate || minDate);

            CalcDiff();
        },
        onSelectTime: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        },
        minDate: minStart,
        defaultDate: minStart
    }).val(minStart);

    $("#end").datetimepicker({
        format: "Y/m/d H:i",
        dayOfWeekStart: "1",
        value: "12:00",
        inline: true,
        lang: "nl",
        minDate: minEnd,
        defaultDate: minEnd,
        onSelectDate: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        },
        onSelectTime: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        }
    }).val(minEnd);

    CalcDiff();
});

function CalcDiff() {
    var start = new Date($("#start").val());
    var end = new Date($("#end").val());

    if (start != null && end != null) { // We have both dates
        var hours = Math.abs(end - start) / 36e5;
        $("#difference").val(hours);
    }

    return hours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
  minStart.setHours(12); 
  minStart.setMinutes(00); 

  minEnd.setHours(12); 
  minEnd.setMinutes(00);
```

Comment: Yes, I just finished creating a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4fa5n7wa/11/  You should setSeconds(0) too.